What is the standard way of writing configuration in flutter?
I am new to flutter and no clear documents for creating a config file.What is the standard way of writing configuration in flutter similar to one below which we write in appsettings.json(.net core)?
   "Travel": {
     "EndPoint": "https://api.openai.com/v1/threads",
     "ApiKey": "sk-123",
     "AssistantId": "asst_123"
   },
   "Home": {
     "EndPoint": "https://api.openai.com/v1/threads",
     "ApiKey": "sk-1234",
     "AssistantId": "asst_1234"
   },
   "Edu": {
     "EndPoint": "https://api.openai.com/v1/threads",
     "ApiKey": "sk-123456",
     "AssistantId": "asst_12345"
     }
 }```


Does this answer your question? Setting environment variables in Flutter

You can create a Dart class to represent the structure and store the configuration data. Here's how you can do it:
class AppConfig {
  static const Map<String, Map<String, String>> config = {
    "Travel": {
      "EndPoint": "https://api.openai.com/v1/threads",
      "ApiKey": "sk-123",
      "AssistantId": "asst_123"
    },
    "Home": {
      "EndPoint": "https://api.openai.com/v1/threads",
      "ApiKey": "sk-1234",
      "AssistantId": "asst_1234"
    },
    "Edu": {
      "EndPoint": "https://api.openai.com/v1/threads",
      "ApiKey": "sk-123456",
      "AssistantId": "asst_12345"
    }
  };
}


In this Dart class:
AppConfig represents the configuration class.
config is a static constant map containing the configuration data.
The keys of the outer map represent different categories (Travel, Home, Edu).
Each category contains a nested map with configuration details (EndPoint, ApiKey, AssistantId).
You can then access this configuration throughout your app like so:
String travelEndPoint = AppConfig.config["Travel"]["EndPoint"];
String travelApiKey = AppConfig.config["Travel"]["ApiKey"];
String travelAssistantId = AppConfig.config["Travel"]["AssistantId"];



In Flutter, several methods commonly used, including the use of JSON files, Dart files (my preferred way), and environment variables (for more sensitive data). I'll try to give you an example of each:

You can use JSON in your project.

First add your JSON config file in your project, somewhere like: config/server.json. Then update the assets in pubspec.yaml:
  assets:
    - config/server.json

Now, you can load your JSON:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<void> loadConfig() async {
  final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('config/server.json');
  final Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
  // Use the jsonMap for configuration
}


You can create a Dart file that contains config settings as constants or a class with static properties. (My preferred way):

class Config {
  final String title;
  final String endPoint;
  final String apiKey;
  final String assisstantId;

  const Config({
    required this.title,
    required this.endPoint,
    required this.apiKey,
    required this.assisstantId,
  });
}

And the config repository is like:
class ConfigRepository {
  static const travel = Config(
    title: 'Travel',
    endPoint: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/threads',
    apiKey: 'sk-123',
    assisstantId: 'asst_123',
  );

  static const home = Config(
    title: 'Home',
    endPoint: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/threads',
    apiKey: 'sk-123',
    assisstantId: 'asst_123',
  );
}

// To access all list together
static List<Config> get list => [travel, home];

// Find property which has the specific name
static Config findByName(String name) => list.firstWhere(
   (l) => l.name == name,
   orElse: () => list[0],
);

This way you can access your data for instance travel data by using ConfigRepository.travel.
This way you can add some method like finding the data by name (or anyth other properties that you want). (as I mentioned in the class.)

You may want to search for environment variable in flutter for sensitive data, looking at packages like flutter_dotenv, envied, etc may help.


Another solution is the use of dart define.

In the main directory of your project (where pubspec.yaml is) put your json file. Split it into 3 different ones. One for each environment. In your case travel-server.json, home-server.json, edu-server.json with keys EndPoint, ApiKey, AssistantId. As it contains sensitive data, those files should not be committed to the repository.
when using flutter run add --dart-define-from-file=<name of environment>-server.json. It can also be added to run config in AndroidStudio and VSCode
In your code read those values like String.fromEnvironment("EndPoint") etc.

